# How to restrict public email id for registration in PHP?

Tags: php, email, restriction

I have a registration form that uses any kind of emails for registration. I want to restrict it to company mail id's only. In other words, no free email service provider's mail id would work for registration.

Comment: Use a database to make a blacklist and then check against that.

Comment: If you are targetting users who could organise changes to their company website, ask that they upload a file, generated by you, to the root of their domain. Google Webmaster does this to prove domain ownership.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea - Would be great if you can give the SQL Query. Here is my database structure: 

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `restricted_mails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain` varchar(955) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; 

The input id=email name=email

Comment: A little research online can give you that answer.

Comment: So in other words, if the email contains "hotmail, gmail, yahoo" etc. it should break. Check out `stripos()` then http://php.net/stripos

Comment: You're also going to need to provide us the way you're checking for allowed/disallowed emails and how they're being passed in the method you're using; if in an array, from a form, a text file etc... As it stands, your question is unclear and too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not provided any additional information as to how E-mail addresses are being defined and/or entered into a form or not, am submitting the following using PHP's `preg_match()` function, along with `b` and `i` pattern delimiters and an array.

`b` - word boundary
`i` - case insensitive

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

The following will match against "gmail" or "Gmail" etc. should someone want to trick the system.

Including Hotmail, Yahoo. You can add to the array.

```
<?php 
$_POST['email'] = "email@Gmail.com";
$data = $_POST['email'];

 if(preg_match("/\b(hotmail|gmail|yahoo)\b/i", $data)){
    echo " Found free Email service.";
    exit;
}

else{
    echo "No match found for free Email service.";
    exit;
}
```

---

Actually, you can use:

```
if(preg_match("/(hotmail|gmail|yahoo)/i", $data))
```

instead of:

```
if(preg_match("/\b(hotmail|gmail|yahoo)\b/i", $data))
```

which gave the same results.

Comment: This is my mail verification code. See if you can help @Fred `if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
 } else {
  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
  $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($row['email'])){
   $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
  }
   
 } `

Comment: @ArijitAich You mentioned *"This is the code to check my mail validation & pre-existence"* in the other answer, along with DB codes. That doesn't reflect your original question, asking to restrict free Email services addresses; which is what I did in my answer. Have you tried my codes?

Comment: @ArijitAich All you need to do is, if the person's email is not a free Email, then you can then continue in the `else` part where it says "No match found for free Email service." with the `if(!filter_var($_POST['email']....` of your code that you posted in comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about a white/black list of domains like the following:

```
$domainWhitelist = ['companydomain.org', 'companydomain.com'];
$domainBlacklist = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com'];
$domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

//white list 
if(in_array($domain, $domainWhitelist)) {
    //allowed
}

//black list
if(!in_array($domain, $domainBlacklist)) {
    //allowed
}
```

Comment: The problem is the number of companies are infinte. I cant provide access to each one of them. Rather i can blocklist the free mail providers who are a handful.

Comment: Sidenote: Depending on their PHP version if `< 5.4` then `$allowed = ['companydomain.org', 'companydomain.com'];` will need to use `array()`.

Comment: @ArijitAich: Then you can do the opposite with a black list.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Who is using PHP < 5.4 for new web apps...? ;)

Comment: I am really new to PHP. Would be great if you can provide me with the codes.

Comment: @vim You would be surprised. I've seen questions lately where OP's were using 4, and many 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: @vim This didn't solve the problem. I tried but its prohibiting all kinds of mail ID domains. Here is my code:

$domainBlacklist = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com'];
$domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));


//black list
if(!in_array($domain, $domainBlacklist)) {
    $error[] = 'Email provided is not an official mail id.';
}

Comment: @ArijitAich Just omit the ! before `in_array()` and it'll work as you expect it to. :)
Full code: `$domainBlacklist = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com']; 
$domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email)); 
//black list 
if(in_array($domain, $domainBlacklist)) { 
    $error[] = 'Email provided is not an official mail id.';
}`
And don't forget to accept the best answer..

Comment: I Think i am doing something wrong. This is the code to check my mail validation & pre-existence. See if you can help: `if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
     $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
 } else {
  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
  $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($row['email'])){
   $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
  }
   
 } `