# Blocking certain domains from php mailer process script or form

Tags: php, forms, email, block, mailer

I keep getting blasted with emails from certain domains or domain extensions. I would like to add a function to mitigate these emails. If somebody could help me with either adding a function to block the form from sending.

Below is the process script i have tried to add code to unsuccessfully.

```
<?php

$mail = $_POST['email_quote'];

/*$subject = "".$_POST['subject'];*/
$to = "contact@editedemail.com";
$subject = "Online Website Quote Request";
$headers = "From: Website <no-reply@editedemail.com>";

$message = "\nPERSONAL INFO";
$message .= "\nFirst Name: " . $_POST['firstname_quote'];
$message .= "\nLast Name: " . $_POST['lastname_quote'];
$message .= "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email_quote'];
$message .= "\nPhone number: " . $_POST['phone_quote'];

$message .= "\n\nVehicle Details";
$message .= "\nYear: " . $_POST['vehicle_year_quote'];
$message .= "\nMake: " . $_POST['vehicle_make_quote'];
$message .= "\nModel: " . $_POST['vehicle_model_quote'];

$message .= "\n\nADDTIONAL INFO";
$message .= "\nLocked out of your vehicle? " . $_POST['option_1'];
$message .= "\nLost All Your Vehicle Keys? " . $_POST['option_2'];
$message .= "\nPush to start ignition? " . $_POST['option_3'];
$message .= "\nRequire new key(s) made? " . $_POST['option_4'];
$message .= "\nRequire new remote(s) made? " . $_POST['option_5'];
$message .= "\nVehicle has keyless entry? " . $_POST['option_6'];

$message  .= "\n\nADDITIONAL NOTES";
$message .= "\nMessage: " . $_POST['message_quote'];

//Receive Variable
$sentOk = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

//Confirmation page
$user = "$mail";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: no-reply@editedemail.com\n";
/*$usermessage = "Thank you for your time. Your request is successfully submitted.\n"; WITH OUT SUMMARY*/
//Confirmation page WITH  SUMMARY
$usermessage = "Your request has been successfully submitted. One of our staff will contact you shortly. If you require immediate assistance with yo$
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);

?>
```

Thank you for any and all help with this.

I have seen multiple examples on stackoverflow but have not been able to implement anything that actually works properly. I end up breaking my form or it just says the form was submitted and breaks the mailer.

Here is one i've tried and failed to get properly working. It will still send a success message on the page itself but will not send any email afterwards worst case or will break the page depending on the edits i make.

```
// You can add as many email addresses as you'd like to this list.
$blacklist = [
    '@mail.ru'
];

// The name of the field representing the email address input
$field_name = 'email_quote';

// The error message to show when an invalid email address is submitted
$error_message = 'This email is not allowed';

// Do not edit below
foreach ($blacklist as $blacklist_email)
{
    if (stripos($post[$field_name], $blacklist_email) !== false)
    {
        throw new Exception($error_message);
    }
}
```

i also tried the following but failed to implement it correctly or possibly forgot to add other code to enable its function..

```
private function validEmail($value) {
    if (!$value || !filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return false; 
    if (preg_match('#@example\.org$#uiD', $value) === 1) return false;
    if (preg_match('#@example\.net$#uiD', $value) === 1) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So, you have an open form that anyone can POST to and it will email whomever the person wants, and you want to try to limit this?

Comment: Is that not called an open relay. You Hosting Company will soon be on your case if it is, because their email server will be getting blacklisted

Comment: In order to really assist here, we would need to see the whole script

Comment: The first attempt you have with the blacklist loop looks like it should work, other than the fact that you're using `$post` instead of `$_POST`. What exact problem are you having with it?

Comment: I really don't like regex for this, personally. Validate that the email address is valid, just like you are doing, and then a [simple lookup with `in_array` should suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28810603/231316). This is way easier to maintain since you don't need to worry about escaping, and you could easily move the list to a dedicated file if it got big. Performance wouldn't be an issue for something like this either.

Comment: the whole script is posted. the two examples are just examples from stackoverflow which never work regardless if $_POST or not. i am looking to implement something that will work and adding either of those examples breaks the script and wont send any email. it's not an open relay by any means just a contact form which uses php script to send the data.